# Neural network: Line detection in Image

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am playing around with Mathematica's new Neural Network toolbox and am trying to teach a network to detect lines in quite noisy images.

An example Input image would look like the following:

[image: Input]

The corresponding (desired) output is an image like this one (currently I am drawing those lines by hand...):

[image: Output]

How would one approach this? In detail:

1. How many Input->Output pairs would I need? Currently I have about 100 but I guess this is not enough.
2. What Network architecture would you recommend? I tried a couple of combinations of Convolution and Ramp/Tanh layers but without amazing results.
3. Is there a more suited loss layer than the standard MeanSquare one for my purpose?
4. Would you even recommend using a neural network for this task?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Why not use techniques from computer vision such as Hough transform?

Comment: @user3683367 Why are you only paying attention to the diagonal lines? Is that a requirement? You seem to be throwing away vertical lines (from noise) which have about same luminosity as the diagonal ones. So how do you know what's noise and what's the real deal? Run these on your source gif and see what you get:
`Binarize@ImageAdjust[ImageConvolve[ImageAdjust[ImageSubtract[gif,.15],1.05], {{-1,0,1},{-2,0,2},{-1,0,1}}],1.1]` or 
`ImageAdjust@GradientFilter[ImageAdjust[ImageSubtract[gif,.1],1.2],{2,.5}]`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The lines are not necessary straight but can become quite curved. Also I only want clear diagonal lines and discard noisy areas/lines. Thats why I initially thought the network approach might be best. As far as I understood the Hough Transform is mostly useful to extract broken lines or?

Comment: @GregoryKlopper These approaches work very well to denoise the image but as you guessed right I do not want vertical lines. Additionally, the area to the left is quite noisy and it is hard to discern clear lines by eye. Thus I did not trace these by hand and I wanted to train the network to not do that either.

Comment: This is a semantic segmentation type problem. The desired output of the network is a heat map (or threshholded heatmap) of whether or not a given pixel belongs to one of your desired pixels. There is an example in the 11.1 docs on semantic segmentation that is a pretty good place to start

Comment: @Yss Do you have a link to the example? I can not find it.

Comment: Pre-processing your image even if you do go with a neural network solution, is a must. Training your network in such a noisy image would require a much more robust network and much longer training.

Comment: In documentation for NetTrain under Applications> Computer Vision.

Comment: The example I was referring to is in the nettrain documentation. I'm not sure of the exact page away from my computer, I think it's applications->computer vision->semantic segmentation. Also, as an alternative to elimianting noise, you can conversely try to add more to get a very robust and noise immune network. In general, if you can see it, a convnet can be made to see it.

Comment: Thank you all for you help! Together with the segmentation example I could find a net that performs extremely well.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend trying a U-Net style network ([Link to the original U-Net article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597)) for segmentation of such features. It has fared well with a small number of inputs for training. I don't use Mathematica but there seems to be at least [one implementation](https://github.com/alihashmiii/UNet-Segmentation-Wolfram) out there. If you're willing to switch to Python, this [Keras implementation](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet) has proven sufficient.

Comment: There is a [pre-trained U-Net on the Neural Net Repo](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/U-Net-Trained-on-Glioblastoma-Astrocytoma-U373-Cells-on-a-Polyacrylamide-Substrate-Data).

Answer (score 2):

In the end I implemented a U-Net style network with some further tweaks to improve the detection of lines that reverse direction.It was a long journey with a lot of fun and frustration along the way.

You can read about it here:
https://elifesciences.org/articles/42288